# Get sqlite file from android device devoid SD card?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I try to get the sqlite file of my android database.
Do I have to generate it, or can i find it in a specific folder on my device?
I work with a SAMSUNG Nexus 7 tablet.

Thanks in advance

Comment: No u cant see it but you can export sqlite file in Sdcard.

Comment: It's the matter, it's no SD card in nexus tablet

Comment: If your phone has no SDcard then Export DB into Phone Memory

Comment: I'am beginner with android, could you give me a link or a tips to do it please? Thanks for your help

Comment: Go to this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16537145/import-export-to-android-sqlite-database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16537145/import-export-to-android-sqlite-database)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

normally the database file is stored here data/data/package/databases  you can use eclipse DB view to show it, what i do normally is copying this file from the package above programmatically into an assets folder,

check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17142081/android-external-database-in-assets-folder/17142477#17142477) to do that

Comment: No, you *cannot* use eclipse to see this unless you are running on an emulator or an engineering device where adbd runs as root, or your program modifies the permissions of its file.