# How to insert the data into the database about 200 rows from the db file?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-database

The database structure will be as follows:

```
city_id     city_name
   1        Hyderabad
   2        pune
   5        mumbai......
```

I want to add the data to my app's database from the .db file which is in the assets folder of the project.

Comment: Actually I wanna add that kind of data to my database...becoz I need to show that data in the login to select there city and send the city of along with the username and password to the server....

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17142081/android-external-database-in-assets-folder

Comment: Yea....that's good and I have a txt with json string how can I use that....to insert the data from that txt file can v do that...

Comment: Can you not convert the txt file into .db file in your computer and then put the db file in the asset folder. It improves the performance of your app  when you want to create the database.

Comment: Yea...thx for the solution...

Comment: No problem should I add that as an answer?

Comment: Yea...u can do that for sure......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good answer in here [Android external database in assets folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17142081/android-external-database-in-assets-folder).

Just to improve the performance of your app, I would suggest that you make the db file in your computer and then import the .db file in the assets folder. (not the .txt file directly)

Answer (score 0):

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
for(int i = 0; i<=5; i++) {
    values.put(city_id, cityId[i]);
    values.put(city_name, cityName[i]);
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
}
```

Comment: City_I'd vl not be increased.... I mean in between some numbers may also move out..